# Set theory understanding notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding what elements certain sets would contain. I cannot find any notes either on the subject, since I don't know what to call the notation.

$\mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$

$\{0,1\}\times \mathbb{N}$

$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$

$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Any help would be appreciated, with either a few examples of elements of these sets, or names of the notation used so that I can find it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_1=\mathbb{N}\times[0,1)=\{(n,x):n\in\mathbb{N},x\in[0,1)\text{ real number}\}$
$A_2=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}=\{(a,n):n\in\mathbb{N},a=0\text{ or }1\}$
$A_3=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}=\{(n,m):n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$

So an example for each of them is:
$(5,\sqrt{2}/2)\in A_1,$ $(0,17)\in A_2$, $(19,729)\in A_3$.

While $A_4=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the space of sequencies made just by $0'$s and $1'$s, e.g. $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_{2k},a_{2k+1},...)$ where $a_{2k+1}=1$ and $a_{2k}=0$.

Comment: Thank you! To be clear about $A_4$ , would that mean that $A_5=\{0,1\}^4$ would be a sequence (0,1,0,1), a sequence of 4 elements? And that $A_4$ is a sequence with $\mathbb{N}$  (countably infinite) elements?

Comment: Sure, because it is meant as $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4):a_i\in\{0,1\}\,\forall i=1,2,3,4\}$. To be precise if the exponent if finite you can call it a tuple, otherwise if you have $\mathbb{N}$ it is a sequence of countably many entries/elements